# How can I alter this function to print all combinations that are one letter away?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

For example, if searchWord = "Hello" I would like to print Aello, Bello, Cello, etc.

```
for i in range(len(searchWord)):
        for letter in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')):
            print(searchWord[:i] + letter + searchWord[i+1:])
```

Comment: `print(searchWord[:i] + chr(letter) + searchWord[i + 1:])`?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Thanks, that was it! One more question. If I want to then go through the list of words that the above code created to see if any of the words are contained in a set that contains words, how would I alter this code?                                                                 
    for i in range(len(searchWord)):
        for letter in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')):
            foundWord = (searchWord[:i] + chr(letter) + searchWord[i+1:])
            if foundWord in mySet:
      print(foundWords)

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

searchWord = 'Hello'

for i in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print(i+searchWord[1:])

>>> aello
>>> bello
>>> cello
```

or

```
[print(i+searchWord[1:]) for i in string.ascii_lowercase]

>>> aello
>>> bello
>>> cello
```